# Button Form Submit not working

Tags: jquery, html

Any ideas why this wont submit the form?(fyi I dont want to use input type='Submit'), function call works.

```
<button  onclick='submitForm()'>Save</button>

function submitForm() {
    alert('Run');
    //Do some more things
    $('form#myForm').submit();
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the rest of your HTML? Namely, does your form have an id of `myForm`?

Comment: add type = submit to the button, do your calculation in function and then it will be automatically submitted.

Comment: @Rex, he doesnt want to use this. :)

Comment: @IvankaTodorova ok missed that, and only $('form #myForm').submit(); or $('#myForm').submit(); will do

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just go with this:

```
<button>Save</button>
```

and this:

```
$("button").click(function() { //change the selector
    alert('hello');
    $("form").submit();//change the selector
});
```

Answer (score 0):

There does not seems to be any error in the code, please check if you have included the jQuery in your page.